# AdMob onRewarded() never called

Tags: java, android, admob, rewardedvideoad

Every other `RewardedVideoAdListener` method is called: `onRewardedVideoAdLoaded()`, `onRewardedVideoAdClosed` etc

But never `onRewarded()`

The video is opened, viewed until end, closed ad normally and returned to app and still `onRewarded()` is not called. Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an incorrect setup in AdMob. "Use third party settings" was selected for reward type instead of allowing AdMob to handle the reward. Set any amount and name for reward, then onRewarded() will be called.