# onUserEarnedReward is never called in Admob 20.1.0

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, google-ads-api

I'm working on converting my Kotlin App to Admob 20.1.0. Running into a problem integrating Rewarded Ads.

The problem is `onUserEarnedReward` is never called. I currently have no way of rewarding the user with the content they unlocked. My code below is placed in an `onClickListener` within an `AppCompatActivity()`

```
if (mRewardedAd != null) {
    mRewardedAd?.show(this, OnUserEarnedRewardListener { // Redundant SAM-constructor 
        fun onUserEarnedReward(rewardItem: RewardItem) { // Function "onUserEarnedReward" is never used 
            
            val rewardAmount = rewardItem.amount
            val rewardType = rewardItem.type
            println("======================= TYPE -  $rewardType /// AMOUNT - $rewardAmount")
            // This never gets called.
        }
    })
} else {
    println("=======================The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.")
}
```

My imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*
import com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardItem
import com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardedAd
import com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardedAdLoadCallback
import com.google.android.gms.ads.OnUserEarnedRewardListener
```

Why am I getting **Redundant SAM-constructor** and **Function "onUserEarnedReward" is never used** ?

Comment: Might this be of help to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187101/admob-onrewarded-never-called?rq=1

Comment: @JackChampagne - Everything is properly configured on AdMob's end. The Rewarded Ad was working great before I upgraded to 20.1.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is you are creating a function in High Order function and not invoking the function.
Please try with below code. it will work

```
       mRewardedAd?.show(this, OnUserEarnedRewardListener { rewardItem ->
        val rewardAmount = rewardItem.amount
        val rewardType = rewardItem.type
        println("======================= TYPE -  $rewardType /// AMOUNT - $rewardAmount")
      }
```

For your better understanding about high order function below code is also work

```
   mRewardedAd?.show(this, OnUserEarnedRewardListener { 
    fun onUserEarnedReward(rewardItem: RewardItem) { 
        val rewardAmount = rewardItem.amount
        val rewardType = rewardItem.type
        println("======================= TYPE -  $rewardType /// AMOUNT - $rewardAmount")
    }
    onUserEarnedReward(it)
})
```

Comment: Can you Explain What exactly diffrence between your snippet code and Joe's snippet code.?

Comment: Joe's snippet is a high order function. and In kotlin you can define function inside function, so joe override the function inside the function,Please check above the second snippet if you call the function it will work.

Answer (score 0):

OnUserEarnedRewardListener should be an interface object that overrides onUserEarnedReward(). Change your code to this

```
if (mRewardedAd != null) {
  mRewardedAd?.show(this, object: OnUserEarnedRewardListener { 
   override fun onUserEarnedReward(rewardItem: RewardItem) { // Function "onUserEarnedReward" is never used 
        
        val rewardAmount = rewardItem.amount
        val rewardType = rewardItem.type
        println("======================= TYPE -  $rewardType /// AMOUNT - $rewardAmount")
        // This never gets called.
    }
  })
} else {
println("=======================The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.")
```

}